# A question about constructing convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Recently I am confused by such an issue: There are a few sequences $X_1,X_2....X_k\in R^N$,$\sum_n X_i(n)$ converges for  i=1,2...k and a sequence $Y\in R^N,\sum_n Y(n)$ diverges, can we find a sequence {$a_n$}, such that all  $\sum_n a_nX_i(n)$ converge for i=1,2....k ,but$\sum_n a_nY(n)$ still diverges?

Comment: Actually,  if for any {$a_n$} $\in cs^{(1)}$ ($ \sum_n a_n$ converges) , $\sum_n a_nb_n$ converges. then {$b_n$} is bounded value($\sum_n |b_{n+1}-b_{n}| < \infty$), I can prove it by constructing. However, I don't know weather it is true when it comes to higher dimensions, these two questions are relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately we cannot always do this. For instance take $Y(n)$ to be the sequence $Y(n) = 1$ for all $n$, so clearly $\sum_n Y(n) = \sum_n 1 = \infty$. And for any sequence $(a_n)$ such that $\sum_n a_n$ converges, we have
$$\sum_n a_nY(n) = \sum_n a_n \cdot 1 = \sum_n a_n \quad\text{which converges}$$

Edit: for your revised question (where $\sum_n a_n$ isn't required to converge), just take the sequence $a_n=1$ for all $n$. Then $a_n X_i(n) = X_i(n)$ and $a_nY(n) = Y(n)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, I found that "$\sum_n a_n$ converges" may be an unnecessary condition.......

Comment: I 'm sorry that I didn't show it correctly.

Comment: Your A no longer addresses the Q but it's not your fault. The Q has been changed.

Comment: I've edited my response to answer the edited question